# Contar hojas de un arbol binario en java

Tags: java

Necesito completar la funcion hojas pero no se como, este es el codigo. Ya he completado otras funciones.

```
public class ArbolBinarioOrdenado
    {
    private ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierda;
    private Integer valor;
    private ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecha;

    // Constructores
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado() 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(null);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(Integer v) 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        // David Sánchez
        this.izquierda = a.izquierda;
        this.setValor(a.getValor());
        this.derecha = a.derecha;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado i, Integer v, ArbolBinarioOrdenado d) 
    {
        this.izquierda = i.izquierda;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = d.derecha;
        // Completar
    }

    // Setters y Getters
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getIzquierda()
    {
        return izquierda;
    }

    public void setIzquierda(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierda)
    {
        this.izquierda = izquierda;
    }

    public Integer getValor()
    {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Integer valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getDerecha()
    {
        return derecha;
    }

    public void setDerecha(ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecha)
    {
        this.derecha = derecha;
    }

    // Otros inspectores
    public void add(Integer v)
    {
        if (v < this.valor)
        {
            if (izquierda != null) 
            {
                izquierda.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                izquierda = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (derecha != null) 
            {
                derecha.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                derecha = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        }
    }
    public String mostrar()
    {
        String cadena = "";

        return cadena;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean buscar(Integer v) 
    {
        boolean resultado = false;
        if (v == this.valor) 
        {
            resultado = true;
        } 
        else if (v < this.valor) 
        {
            if (this.izquierda != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.izquierda.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (this.derecha != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.derecha.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void mostrarIn()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarIn();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarIn();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPre()
    {
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPre();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPre();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPos()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }
    public void anular()
    {
        // Álvaro Carballo
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
    }
    public boolean arbolVacio()
    {
        // Carolina Ávila
        boolean vacio = false;
        if((this.valor==null)&&(this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            vacio = true;
        }
        return vacio;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado construirArbol(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierdo, int valor, ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecho)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado union = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return union;
        // Completar ¿?
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoIzquierdo()
    {
        // Antonio Hernández
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoI = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoI = this.izquierda;
        return hijoI;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoDerecho()
    {
        // Alberto Arrojo
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoD = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoD = this.derecha;
        return hijoD;
    }
    public int raiz()
    {
        return this.valor;
    }
    public boolean esHoja(int v)
    {
        // José Manuel Fortún
        boolean resultado = true;
        if((this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            resultado = true;
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void eliminarArbol()
    {
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
        // El recolector eliminará el objeto
    }
    public int altura()
    {
        // Recursivo
        int altura = 0;
        // Base
        // Caso Recursivo
        return altura;
        // Completar
    }
    public int hojas()
    {
        int hojas = 0;
        // Recorrer todo el árbol
        // Cuando llegue a un nodo, contar si es hoja o no
        return hojas;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarDato(int x)
    {
        // Parecido a hojas()
        int cuenta = 0;
        return cuenta;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodos()
    {
        // Javier Martín
        int cuenta = 0;
        if(this.valor==null)
        {
            cuenta = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cuenta = 1;
        }
        if(this.izquierda!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.izquierda.contarNodos();

        }
        if(this.derecha!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.derecha.contarNodos();

        }
        return cuenta;
    }
    public boolean existe(int x)
    {
        boolean existe = false;
        return existe;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean comparar(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a, ArbolBinarioOrdenado b)
    {
        boolean iguales = true;
        return iguales;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo(ArbolBinarioOrdenado x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return espejo;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado buscarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado insertarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoDerecho()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoIzquierdo()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado eliminarOrd(int x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hacerOrd(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodosEnNivel(int nivel)
    {
        int nodos = 0;
        return nodos;
        // Completar
    }

    }

    // Constructores
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado() 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(null);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(Integer v) 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        // 
        this.izquierda = a.izquierda;
        this.setValor(a.getValor());
        this.derecha = a.derecha;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado i, Integer v, ArbolBinarioOrdenado d) 
    {
        this.izquierda = i.izquierda;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = d.derecha;
        // Completar
    }

    // Setters y Getters
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getIzquierda()
    {
        return izquierda;
    }

    public void setIzquierda(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierda)
    {
        this.izquierda = izquierda;
    }

    public Integer getValor()
    {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Integer valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getDerecha()
    {
        return derecha;
    }

    public void setDerecha(ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecha)
    {
        this.derecha = derecha;
    }

    // Otros inspectores
    public void add(Integer v)
    {
        if (v < this.valor)
        {
            if (izquierda != null) 
            {
                izquierda.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                izquierda = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (derecha != null) 
            {
                derecha.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                derecha = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        }
    }
    public String mostrar()
    {
        String cadena = "";

        return cadena;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean buscar(Integer v) 
    {
        boolean resultado = false;
        if (v == this.valor) 
        {
            resultado = true;
        } 
        else if (v < this.valor) 
        {
            if (this.izquierda != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.izquierda.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (this.derecha != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.derecha.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void mostrarIn()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarIn();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarIn();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPre()
    {
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPre();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPre();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPos()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }
    public void anular()
    {
        // 
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
    }
    public boolean arbolVacio()
    {
        // 
        boolean vacio = false;
        if((this.valor==null)&&(this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            vacio = true;
        }
        return vacio;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado construirArbol(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierdo, int valor, ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecho)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado union = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return union;
        // Completar ¿?
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoIzquierdo()
    {

        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoI = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoI = this.izquierda;
        return hijoI;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoDerecho()
    {
        // 
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoD = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoD = this.derecha;
        return hijoD;
    }
    public int raiz()
    {
        return this.valor;
    }
    public boolean esHoja(int v)
    {
        // 
        boolean resultado = true;
        if((this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            resultado = true;
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void eliminarArbol()
    {
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
        // El recolector eliminará el objeto
    }
    public int altura()
    {
        // Recursivo
        int altura = 0;
        // Base
        // Caso Recursivo
        return altura;
        // Completar
    }
    public int hojas()
    {
        int hojas = 0;
        // Recorrer todo el árbol
        // Cuando llegue a un nodo, contar si es hoja o no
        return hojas;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarDato(int x)
    {
        // Parecido a hojas()
        int cuenta = 0;
        return cuenta;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodos()
    {
        // 
        int cuenta = 0;
        if(this.valor==null)
        {
            cuenta = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cuenta = 1;
        }
        if(this.izquierda!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.izquierda.contarNodos();

        }
        if(this.derecha!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.derecha.contarNodos();

        }
        return cuenta;
    }
    public boolean existe(int x)
    {
        boolean existe = false;
        return existe;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean comparar(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a, ArbolBinarioOrdenado b)
    {
        boolean iguales = true;
        return iguales;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo(ArbolBinarioOrdenado x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return espejo;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado buscarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado insertarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoDerecho()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoIzquierdo()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado eliminarOrd(int x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hacerOrd(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodosEnNivel(int nivel)
    {
        int nodos = 0;
        return nodos;
        // Completar
    }

    }


    // Constructores
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado() 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(null);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(Integer v) 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        // David Sánchez
        this.izquierda = a.izquierda;
        this.setValor(a.getValor());
        this.derecha = a.derecha;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado i, Integer v, ArbolBinarioOrdenado d) 
    {
        this.izquierda = i.izquierda;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = d.derecha;
        // Completar
    }

    // Setters y Getters
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getIzquierda()
    {
        return izquierda;
    }

    public void setIzquierda(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierda)
    {
        this.izquierda = izquierda;
    }

    public Integer getValor()
    {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Integer valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getDerecha()
    {
        return derecha;
    }

    public void setDerecha(ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecha)
    {
        this.derecha = derecha;
    }

    // Otros inspectores
    public void add(Integer v)
    {
        if (v < this.valor)
        {
            if (izquierda != null) 
            {
                izquierda.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                izquierda = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (derecha != null) 
            {
                derecha.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                derecha = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        }
    }
    public String mostrar()
    {
        String cadena = "";

        return cadena;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean buscar(Integer v) 
    {
        boolean resultado = false;
        if (v == this.valor) 
        {
            resultado = true;
        } 
        else if (v < this.valor) 
        {
            if (this.izquierda != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.izquierda.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (this.derecha != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.derecha.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void mostrarIn()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarIn();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarIn();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPre()
    {
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPre();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPre();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPos()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }
    public void anular()
    {
        // Álvaro Carballo
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
    }
    public boolean arbolVacio()
    {
        // Carolina Ávila
        boolean vacio = false;
        if((this.valor==null)&&(this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            vacio = true;
        }
        return vacio;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado construirArbol(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierdo, int valor, ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecho)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado union = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return union;
        // Completar ¿?
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoIzquierdo()
    {
        // Antonio Hernández
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoI = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoI = this.izquierda;
        return hijoI;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoDerecho()
    {
        // Alberto Arrojo
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoD = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoD = this.derecha;
        return hijoD;
    }
    public int raiz()
    {
        return this.valor;
    }
    public boolean esHoja(int v)
    {
        // José Manuel Fortún
        boolean resultado = true;
        if((this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            resultado = true;
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void eliminarArbol()
    {
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
        // El recolector eliminará el objeto
    }
    public int altura()
    {
        // Recursivo
        int altura = 0;
        // Base
        // Caso Recursivo
        return altura;
        // Completar
    }
    public int hojas()
    {
        int hojas = 0;
        // Recorrer todo el árbol
        // Cuando llegue a un nodo, contar si es hoja o no
        return hojas;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarDato(int x)
    {
        // Parecido a hojas()
        int cuenta = 0;
        return cuenta;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodos()
    {
        // Javier Martín
        int cuenta = 0;
        if(this.valor==null)
        {
            cuenta = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cuenta = 1;
        }
        if(this.izquierda!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.izquierda.contarNodos();

        }
        if(this.derecha!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.derecha.contarNodos();

        }
        return cuenta;
    }
    public boolean existe(int x)
    {
        boolean existe = false;
        return existe;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean comparar(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a, ArbolBinarioOrdenado b)
    {
        boolean iguales = true;
        return iguales;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo(ArbolBinarioOrdenado x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return espejo;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado buscarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado insertarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoDerecho()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoIzquierdo()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado eliminarOrd(int x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hacerOrd(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodosEnNivel(int nivel)
    {
        int nodos = 0;
        return nodos;
        // Completar
    }

    }

    // Constructores
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado() 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(null);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(Integer v) 
    {
        this.izquierda = null;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = null;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        // 
        this.izquierda = a.izquierda;
        this.setValor(a.getValor());
        this.derecha = a.derecha;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado(ArbolBinarioOrdenado i, Integer v, ArbolBinarioOrdenado d) 
    {
        this.izquierda = i.izquierda;
        this.setValor(v);
        this.derecha = d.derecha;
        // Completar
    }

    // Setters y Getters
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getIzquierda()
    {
        return izquierda;
    }

    public void setIzquierda(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierda)
    {
        this.izquierda = izquierda;
    }

    public Integer getValor()
    {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Integer valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado getDerecha()
    {
        return derecha;
    }

    public void setDerecha(ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecha)
    {
        this.derecha = derecha;
    }

    // Otros inspectores
    public void add(Integer v)
    {
        if (v < this.valor)
        {
            if (izquierda != null) 
            {
                izquierda.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                izquierda = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (derecha != null) 
            {
                derecha.add(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                derecha = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado(v);
            }
        }
    }
    public String mostrar()
    {
        String cadena = "";

        return cadena;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean buscar(Integer v) 
    {
        boolean resultado = false;
        if (v == this.valor) 
        {
            resultado = true;
        } 
        else if (v < this.valor) 
        {
            if (this.izquierda != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.izquierda.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (this.derecha != null) 
            {
                resultado = this.derecha.buscar(v);
            } 
            else 
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void mostrarIn()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarIn();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarIn();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPre()
    {
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPre();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPre();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarPos()
    {
        if(izquierda!=null)
        {
            izquierda.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(derecha!=null)
        {
            derecha.mostrarPos();
        }
        if(valor==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Árbol vacío");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }
    public void anular()
    {
        // 
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
    }
    public boolean arbolVacio()
    {
        // 
        boolean vacio = false;
        if((this.valor==null)&&(this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            vacio = true;
        }
        return vacio;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado construirArbol(ArbolBinarioOrdenado izquierdo, int valor, ArbolBinarioOrdenado derecho)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado union = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return union;
        // Completar ¿?
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoIzquierdo()
    {

        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoI = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoI = this.izquierda;
        return hijoI;
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoDerecho()
    {
        // 
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado hijoD = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        hijoD = this.derecha;
        return hijoD;
    }
    public int raiz()
    {
        return this.valor;
    }
    public boolean esHoja(int v)
    {
        // 
        boolean resultado = true;
        if((this.izquierda==null)&&(this.derecha==null))
        {
            resultado = true;
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void eliminarArbol()
    {
        this.izquierda=null;
        this.derecha=null;
        this.setValor(null);
        // El recolector eliminará el objeto
    }
    public int altura()
    {
        // Recursivo
        int altura = 0;
        // Base
        // Caso Recursivo
        return altura;
        // Completar
    }
    public int hojas()
    {
        int hojas = 0;
        // Recorrer todo el árbol
        // Cuando llegue a un nodo, contar si es hoja o no
        return hojas;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarDato(int x)
    {
        // Parecido a hojas()
        int cuenta = 0;
        return cuenta;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodos()
    {
        // 
        int cuenta = 0;
        if(this.valor==null)
        {
            cuenta = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cuenta = 1;
        }
        if(this.izquierda!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.izquierda.contarNodos();

        }
        if(this.derecha!=null)
        {
            cuenta+=this.derecha.contarNodos();

        }
        return cuenta;
    }
    public boolean existe(int x)
    {
        boolean existe = false;
        return existe;
        // Completar
    }
    public boolean comparar(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a, ArbolBinarioOrdenado b)
    {
        boolean iguales = true;
        return iguales;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo(ArbolBinarioOrdenado x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado espejo = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return espejo;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado buscarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado insertarOrd(int valor)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoDerecho()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado extremoIzquierdo()
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado eliminarOrd(int x)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public ArbolBinarioOrdenado hacerOrd(ArbolBinarioOrdenado a)
    {
        ArbolBinarioOrdenado arbol = new ArbolBinarioOrdenado();
        return arbol;
        // Completar
    }
    public int contarNodosEnNivel(int nivel)
    {
        int nodos = 0;
        return nodos;
        // Completar
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy parecido a contar nodos, sólo que se cuenta como hoja cuando no tiene más izquierda ni derecha, yo elegí hacer un recorrido in, pero da el mismo resultado con pre o pos. Tal vez sea importante preguntar si un árbol vacío cuenta como hoja, pues en ese caso debe verificarse que this.valor no sea nulo para que sea hoja.

```
public int contarHojas() 
{
        int cuenta = 0;
        if(this.izquierda == null && this.derecha == null)
        {
            cuenta = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.izquierda != null) 
            {
              cuenta += contarHojas(this.izquierda);
            }
            if (this.derecha != null)
            {
              cuenta += contarHojas(this.derecha);
            }            
        }
        return cuenta;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Nodo{
  int dato;
  Nodo izq;
  Nodo der;
  public Nodo(int x){
     this.dato=x;
  }
}

class ArbolBin{  
    public int nodosHoja(){
       return nodosHojasR(raiz);
    }
    private int nodosHojasR(Nodo tmp){
       int cuenta = 0;
       if(tmp.izq == null && tmp.der == null)
          cuenta = 1;
       else{
          if (tmp.izq != null) 
             cuenta += nodosHojasR(tmp.izq);
          if (tmp.der != null)
             cuenta += nodosHojasR(tmp.der);
       }
       return cuenta;
  }
```

}

Comment: Considera añadir una explicación de tu código para que otros usuarios se puedan guiar